# How to iterate through numerical file names with bash script?

Tags: bash

So I have a bash script which I am trying to use to run multiple test sets of input/output for a simple program. The files are named input1.txt, input2.txt, expected1.txt, expected2.txt, etc. At the moment I am trying

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /dev/null > ../log
for i in {1..5}
do
    java VanRentalSystem ../input\$i.txt >> ../log;
    diff ../log ../expected\$i.txt
done
```

This is not working, as bash isn't translating the variable 'i' into the correct number.
Assuming all files are in the directory above the current one, how should I rewrite the two lines inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /dev/null > ../log
for i in {1..5}
do
    java VanRentalSystem ../input$i.txt >> ../log;
    diff ../log ../expected$i.txt
done
```

Comment: you can debug it in easy way (e.g for checking generated file name) with adding `set -x` command in second line of script.